# Get Module Name Programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, war

I add a new Google Cloud Module to my Android Studio project to create a backend servlet that I build as a WAR and deploy to Jetty (or to Google Cloud). The WAR file name is `<module-name>.war` (eg. backend.war). When deploying the WAR file to Jetty the servlet's URL is `https://<server-fqdn>/<module-name>`. The Android client code has to HTTP POST to that URL. How do I get the servlet  module name programmatically in the Android client code so it can hit the servlet? Even if I later change the servlet module name, I don't want to have to revise the Android client Java code to keep it synced with the backend servlet name.

Answer (score 2):

Module names are only available at compile time. You cannot get them programmatically at run time. Instead, you should will need a way to specify the URL in your code. One way to do this is to have a class with a `public static final String` that is accessible by all code that needs to know the URL.

Comment: Is there a way for a Gradle task (or something else) to rename a module to the value of an object specified in code (like a public static final String or a string resource in strings.xml etc)?

Comment: @Matthew yes, you can use gradle to set values in BuildConfig or as resources.

Comment: OK, how do you use gradle to set values in BuildConfig or as resources?

Comment: @Matthew If you google "android gradle buildconfig", you will probably find an answer sooner than if you wait for me to do it for you.